# Interpolation between derivatives

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

I am trying to prove the following:

Let $u \in W^{2,2}(\mathbb R)$. Then $\| u^\prime \|_{L^2}^2 \leq \| u \|_{L^2} \| u^{\prime \prime} \|_{L^2}$ holds (these are meant to be weak derivatives).

---

As a first step to tackle the problem I want to prove it for testfunctions $\psi \in C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$.

Using partial integration it holds:
$\displaystyle \| \psi\,^\prime \|_{L^2}^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} | \psi\,^\prime |^2 dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \psi\,^\prime \psi\,^\prime dx = [\psi\,^\prime \psi]_{-\infty}^{+\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \psi \psi\,^{\prime \prime} dx$.

As $\psi$ and $\psi\,^\prime$ both have compact support, the the term $[\psi\,^\prime \psi]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$ vanishes and we are left with:
$\displaystyle \| \psi\,^\prime \|_{L^2}^2 = - \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \psi \psi\,^{\prime \prime} dx$.

---

(1) Does this inequality have a name?

(2) Isn't it weird, that there is a minus sign? On the left hand side we have a norm!

(3) I have read that this proof continues using Hölder's inequality. But to use that we would require $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |\psi \psi\,^{\prime \prime}| dx$ (with the absolute value!).

Can anyone help me out with these to problems? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have:
$$ \left\| \psi' \right\|_{L^2}^2 = -\int_\mathbb{R}\psi\psi''\,dx \tag{1}$$
the inequality:
$$ \left\| \psi' \right\|_{L^2}^2 \leq \left\|\psi\right\|_{L^2}\cdot\left\|\psi''\right\|_{L^2}\tag{2}$$
just follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Nothing strange in the minus sign in the RHS of $(1)$: just think to any non-negative test function that is concave ($\psi''<0$) over its support.

The general version of this inequality is known as the [Gagliardo-Niremberg interpolation inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really helped. I have one additional question: Via density arguments I have to show the inequality for $u \in W^{2,2}(\mathbb R)$.

Is it correct to use: $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $W^{2,2}(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: @KennyH: yes, it is the usual argument.

Comment: My approach is then to pick an arbitrary function $u \in W^{2,2}(\mathbb R)$ and let $(\psi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$ be an approximation sequence with $\| u - \psi_n \|_{L^2} \to 0$ ($n \to \infty$).

If I now write:  
$\| u^\prime \|_{L^2}^2 = \lim \| \psi_n^\prime \|_{L^2}^2 \leq \lim \left( \| \psi_n\|_{L^2} \cdot \| \psi_n^{\prime \prime}\|_{L^2} \right) = \| u \|_{L^2} \cdot \| u^{\prime \prime} \|_{L^2}$
I have used that it also holds
$\| u^\prime - \varphi_n^\prime \|_{L^2} \to 0$ (as $n \to \infty$).
(and the same for the 2nd weak-der.). Can I do this???

Comment: @KennyH: you have to exploit density with respect to the Sobolev norm, not just the $L^2$ norm, hence $\|u-\psi_n\|_{W^{2,2}}\to 0$ and everything works nice.

Comment: Ahhh, brilliant. I've worked it out. Do you happen to have a reference to quote the density with respect to the Sobolev norm?
I only know the result $C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb R)$ (more precisely even $C_0^0(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb R)$).